# Axiom of comprehension

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms

If $\varphi$ is a formula with $y$ not free in $\varphi$, then the axiom of comprehension tells us that

$$\forall z \exists y \forall x (x \in y\iff x \in z \land \varphi(x))$$

Wht does $y$ is not free in $\varphi$ exactly mean? Is it just that 'the formula $\varphi$ does not contain a variable $y$' (modulo subsitution to another name)?

Comment: Intuitively, the axioms asserts the existence of a certain set $y$ depending on a condition $\varphi$. Thus, the condition cannot involve the same set $y$, in order to avoid some sort of circularity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free means not bound by a quantifier.  So, the formula $x < y$ has $y$ free.  But, $\exists y, x < y$ is not free.  The reason this is necessary is because of the quantifier $\exists y$ at the beginning of the Axiom.  Since it is bound in $\varphi$, you could just replace it with $w$ or some other variable.  If it were free in $\varphi$ it would become bound by the Axiom, and wouldn't have the intended meaning.